Adding a colorpicker feature to the wagtail editor
I am wondering if it is possible to add a colorpicker feature to the Wagtail editor. I would like to select a portion of the text and change its color.
I've researched and found that there is a feature in the draftail documentation but it is still unclear for me  how can I add it to the wagtail.
